# WooCommerce - Add to Cart / Remove item from Cart works only with base url

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, woocommerce, permalinks

I've experienced a problem when a strange situation is happening - I can only add/remove items to cart using the base URL.
Works:

```
<base_url>/?addtocart=10 | <base_url>/?remove_item=<item_key>&_wpnonce=<nonce>
```

Doesn't work:

```
<base_url>/<cart_slug>/?addtocart=10 | <base_url>/<cart_slug>/?remove_item=<item_key>&_wpnonce=<nonce>
```

Any idea why it works that way?